# form not getting submitted on onchange event

Tags: php, forms, select, drop-down-menu, submit

Throws error when i select any option from drop-down i.e **this.form.submit() is not defined**  - My code is like this:

```
<form action="entity_report.php" method="GET" onsubmit="return makeSelection();">
    <div align="center"">
      <select name="state" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option>Choose One To Submit This Form</option>
        <option value="CA">CA</option>
        <option value="VA">VA</option>
     </select>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" value="Click here">
</form>
```

Comment: I have tested your code and its working my side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write jquery function for select change of javascript

```
$("state").change(function() {
   $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: this will call when dropdown list item selected. In that it calls form submit so it calls finally 'makeSelection() function

Answer (score 2):

possibly in connection with `<form ... onsubmit="return makeSelection();">` ?! try setting an id to your form and access it via id.

Answer (score 2):

You could also give your form a name="myform" and use: onchange="myform.submit();"

Comment: no.. i have tried it as well, i think its getting conflicted.. wd some of my code

Answer (score 2):

`this.form.submit()` can't be defined. In this context, 'this' refers to your select-tag. Your select-tag doesn't have a child called 'form'.

To get this right, you need to give your form a name by using the `name` attribute, i.e.

```
<form name="myform" action="entity_report.php" method="GET" onsubmit="return makeSelection();"> 
... 
</form>
```

and access it via the document:

```
<select name="state" onchange="document.myform.submit();">
```

**EDIT**
While testing I found out, that the onsubmit event won't get called when submitting a form manually. Workaround I found would be to add `document.myform.onsubmit();` before the call to `submit()`

Comment: Just tried it, works like a charm for me. Tested it only in Chrome. Are you sure you added `name="myform"` to your form-tag?

If it is still not working you can try others methods of accessing "myform":
`document.forms["myform"]` or `document.forms.myform`

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript function to submit your form..

```
<select name="state" onchange="submit_my_form(this);">

<script>
function submit_my_form(myfield)
{
   myfield.form.submit();
}
</script>
```